Symfony - Error thrown while running command "lexik:jwt:generate-keypair"
I'm trying to generate a set of keypairs that will be used to encode the to-be generated JSON Web Tokens.
But i get this error:
php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair
[critical] Error thrown while running command "lexik:jwt:generate-keypair". Message: "error:80000003:system library::No such process"

In GenerateKeyPairCommand.php line 161:

  error:80000003:system library::No such process  


lexik:jwt:generate-keypair [--dry-run] [--skip-if-exists] [--overwrite]

I already have openssl ext enabled in my php.ini
extension=openssl


So I tried to use the command again on git bash where openssl is installed but didn't work, so i generated the keys with openssl directly from it.
To generate private key:
openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem

and to generate the public key:
openssl rsa -in config/jwt/private.pem -pubout > config/jwt/public.pem


I don't understand why symfony does not explicitly say that OpenSSL is required on the OS for this action ‍♂️

I suggest to use a passphrase and more secured key like in 1.x doc : openssl genrsa -out app/config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096 and
openssl rsa -pubout -in app/config/jwt/private.pem -out app/var/jwt/public.pem
